# Using testfor command to constantly fill hunger bar

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way that I can use the testfor command to constantly fill up the hunger bar? Is so, please leave the command below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best and easiest way to do this would be to give all players the saturation effect constantly, instead of trying to do it only when a player is hungry.

```
/effect @a 23 1000000 1 1
```

Which gives all players Saturation I for 1000000 seconds, and hides the particles given off by the effect. The advantage to setting the time to such a large number is so that the effect remaining time displays as `xx:xx` to indicate to the player that the saturation effect is permanent, and that they don't need to worry about food.

Run this command on a clock input of some sort and hide command block output with `/gamerule commandBlockOutput false` and you're all set.

Comment: what does the saturation effect do?

Comment: @user3487713 The saturation effect fills the player's hunger bar by 1 per tick. It essentially ensures that a player can't get hungry.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect give @a saturation 1000000 1 1`

Answer (score 0):

For 1.15+ use

> /effect give @a saturation 1000000 1 1